# Hadoop Administration - Two node cluster

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing

I'm trying to install Hadoop Two node Cluster.

1. What is the best practice to setup two node cluster in terms of running master and slaves daemons?
2. If I run Namenode and Jobtracer as Masters in one machine and Secondary Namenode, Tasktracker and Datanode as Slaves in second machine, will it become a two node cluster?
3. In any of the above case, can i set the replication factor as 1? and why note replication factor as 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can even install Hadoop in single machine in pseudo mode.

**Only for practicing**

Case 1:

1. Install NN, SNN, DN, JT, TT in master and install DN, TT in slave
2. By this way you can configure `replication factor as 2`

Case 2:

1. Install NN, SNN, JT in master and install DN, TT in slave
2. By this you can configure `replication factor as 1`

Comment: Are the above mentioned cases define 2 node cluster?

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is helpful for me.